# Check if item exists in given daterange CAML Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

I have following problem: I build a query which search for me items in sharepoint list which checks if item in given daterange exists when creating a new item. Additionally I have query with the username of adding user and I exclude the statuses of Cancel and Pending. This almost works but when for example I have item on list with Start Date (yyyy-MM-dd): 2019-06-03 and Due Date: 2019-06-07. I want to add item with both Start Date and Due Date: 2019-06-05 then the query didn't return me an exisiting item on the list.. but for example when I'm adding new item with Start Date: 2019-06-01 and Due Date 2019-06-04 it returns me an before added item. Please help me to refactor it because I don't have a idea how to do it.

```
<Where>
<And>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <And>
                <Geq>
                    <FieldRef Name='StartDate' />
                     <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-06-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
                </Geq>
                <Leq>
                    <FieldRef Name='StartDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-06-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
                </Leq>
            </And>
            <And>
                <Geq>
                    <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-06-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
                </Geq>
                <Leq>
                    <FieldRef Name='DueDate' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-06-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
                </Leq>
            </And>
        </Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Employee' />
            <Value Type='PersonOrGroup'>User Name</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
    <And>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Canceled</Value>
        </Neq>
         <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Rejected</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</And>
</Where>
```